# One background for two elements CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have only one background for two elements, and not two times the same background.
It's for this

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
 
document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    let x = evt.clientX / innerWidth;
    let y = evt.clientY / innerHeight;
 
    root.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', x);
    root.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', y);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200');

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1D1F20;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.gradient-border {
  --borderWidth: 3px;
  background: #1D1F20;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
}

.gradient-border:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  height: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  width: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  background: radial-gradient(at calc(var(--mouse-x, 0) * 100%) calc(var(--mouse-y, 0) * 100%), purple 5%, transparent 90%) no-repeat 0 0;
  border-radius: calc(2 * var(--borderWidth));
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
```

If I'm on the right of the screen, I want the right button "border" more colored than left button.

But for the moment, two buttons got exactly the same background.

Can you help me, please?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: then you need to set for each `.gradient-border` its own `--mouse-x`and `--mouse-y` relative to that specific node. the css class ain't aware where it is rendered on the screen to subtract the offset for each "instance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the style applies o each "instance" of `.gradient-border` individually, so you can't use the same `--mouse-x` and `--mouse-y` for all of them; you need to compute and assign it to each node.

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
 
document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    for(let node of document.querySelectorAll(".gradient-border")){
      let box = node.getBoundingClientRect();
      let x = (evt.clientX - box.x) / box.width;
      let y = (evt.clientY - box.y) / box.height;
      node.style.setProperty("--mouse-x", x * 100 + "%");
      node.style.setProperty("--mouse-y", y * 100 + "%");
      node.textContent = x.toFixed(3) + "\n" + y.toFixed(3);
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200');

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1D1F20;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.gradient-border {
  --borderWidth: 3px;
  background: #1D1F20;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
}

.gradient-border:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  height: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  width: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  background: radial-gradient(at var(--mouse-x, 0) var(--mouse-y, 0), purple 5%, transparent 90%) no-repeat 0 0;
  border-radius: calc(2 * var(--borderWidth));
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid changing the value of variable within the `root` element, change it only inside each element and you will have different backgrounds. Use `evt.target` instead of `root`.

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
 
document.addEventListener('mousemove', evt => {
    let x = evt.clientX / innerWidth;
    let y = evt.clientY / innerHeight;
 
    evt.target.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', x);
    evt.target.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', y);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200');

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1D1F20;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.gradient-border {
  --borderWidth: 3px;
  background: #1D1F20;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--borderWidth);
}

.gradient-border:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
  height: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  width: calc(100% + var(--borderWidth) * 2);
  background: radial-gradient(at calc(var(--mouse-x, 0) * 100%) calc(var(--mouse-y, 0) * 100%), purple 5%, transparent 90%) no-repeat 0 0;
  border-radius: calc(2 * var(--borderWidth));
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
<div class="box gradient-border">lama</div>
```